# Linux-Ubuntu: Shared memory of a pointer char* inside of a struct

Tags: c, linux, struct, dynamic, shared-memory

I'm having a memory error (i think) with a char* inside my struct, i'm using linux and just trying to use a Shared Memory to change the character of this char* msg inside my struct between Father Executable and Child Executable.

This is the error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgpX8.png)

> START executable:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include "test.h"
#include <string.h>

int main(){
key_t shmKEY,shmKEY2;
shmKEY= ftok(".",'a');
shmKEY2= ftok(".",'b');

int shmID = shmget(shmKEY,sizeof(struct CHAR),IPC_CREAT | 0664);
int shmID2 = shmget(shmKEY2, sizeof(char)*4, IPC_CREAT | 0664);
struct CHAR* A;

A=shmat(shmID,NULL,0);
A->msg = shmat(shmID2, NULL, 0);

strcpy(A->msg,"Alex");

printf("[%s]",A->msg);
printf("\n");

pid_t pid;
pid=fork();
if(pid<0){
    perror("ERRORE FORK\n");
}
else if(pid==0){
    execl("./SECOND","./SECOND",NULL);
    exit(1);
}

if(pid>0){
    wait(NULL);
    strcpy(A->msg,"wat?");
    printf("PAPA': [%s]",A->msg);
    
    printf("\n");
}




shmctl(shmID,IPC_RMID,0);
shmctl(shmID2,IPC_RMID,0);
return 0;
```

}

> SECOND executable

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
key_t shmKEY,shmKEY2;
shmKEY= ftok(".",'a');
shmKEY2= ftok(".",'b');

int shmID = shmget(shmKEY,0,IPC_CREAT | 0664);
int shmID2 = shmget(shmKEY2,0,IPC_CREAT | 0664);
struct CHAR* A;

A=shmat(shmID,NULL,0);

A->msg=shmat(shmID2,NULL,0);


printf("DEBUG0\n");
printf("[%s]",A->msg);
strcpy(A->msg,"Romy");

printf("[%s]",A->msg);

printf("\n");
printf("DEBUG1\n"); 
return 0;
```

}

> HEADER

```
#ifndef _TEST_H
#define _TEST_H
struct CHAR{
char* msg;
};

#endif
```

> MAKEFILE

```
All: START SECOND

START:main.o
    gcc main.o -o START

SECOND:second.o
    gcc second.o -o SECOND

second.o:second.c test.h
    gcc -c second.c     

main.o: main.c test.h
    gcc -c main.c

clean:
    rm *.o START SECOND
```

Comment: You are storing a pointer value in shared memory. That pointer value will only be meaningful to the process that stored it, but will be a junk, invalid pointer value for any other process that retrieves it (except when it has just been forked). In short, **do not store pointers in shared memory**.

Comment: Maybe not related, but `strcpy(A->msg,"Alex");` copies 5 bytes (remember the terminating null byte) when you have only allocated 4.